# How do I flush stdin in PHP after using fgetc(STDIN)?

Tags: php

If the user types in multiple characters when `fgetc(STDIN)` is called, another call to `fgetc(STDIN)` won't ever ask for a new character and will use the next character in the buffer. One way I solved this was creating the following function:

```
<?php
    function get_char_from_stdin() {
        if (($char = fgetc(STDIN)) != "\n")
            fgets(STDIN);
        return $char;
    }
?>
```

Is there a more elegant solution than the above?

P.S. Please pardon me if my terminology is off. Please correct any misused terms. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Does this work on Windows? I'm using a Mac right now.

Comment: It seems it's work on windows. I tried `php -r "while($char != '.'){$char = fgetc(STDIN); echo $char;}"` and it works, I can type chars !

Comment: By the way, `$char` is undefined at the beginning of that script, but unless you tell PHP to do otherwise, it'll just happily continue chugging along (which I personally find counterproductive).

Comment: Ok, my script is a bad script, it's a bad answer, I don't like it too ! I can delete my post if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STDIN is buffered so in order to get the first char entered after you called your function, you have to open a new stream with an empty buffer.

```
function get_char_from_stdin() {
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    return fgetc($stdin);
}
```

Comment: Ok, turns out this only works for one linebreak, but it will still just take the next line as input.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will still just take the next line as input"?

Comment: It doesn't skip lines entered before the function is called, nor does it skip empty lines. All it does is read one char of the first line, then skip the rest of this line and the next call will read the second line even if you entered 5 lines in between the calls. I think what you really want is that it skips everything entered between the function calls and when you call it waits for the next input.

Comment: Finally got a chance to try it out. It works better than my function and I think it is acceptable. Thanks.